# Comparison prop file values with backend values

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

Need help on the below.

I want to read values from properties file and properties file key and value as below :
org.cc.bu.combo=A1289||B2234,A8976||B7765

And I will receive key and value from backend as  unit=A1289 and cost=B2234,

I want to compare properties values  A1289||B2234  with  unit=A1289 and cost=B2234.  If it match then I need to print matched otherwise to print not matched.

I need to write in .java file but within Mule project only to use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Java to do that. It can be done in DataWeave.

Input:

```
{
    "unit": "A1289",
    "cost" : "B2234"
}
```

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var props = "A1289||B2234,A8976||B7765" // replace with 
p('org.cc.bu.combo')
fun parseProps(p)= p splitBy ',' map ($ splitBy '||') reduce ((item, acc={}) -> acc ++ {(item[0]): item[1]})
---
not isEmpty(parseProps(props) filterObject ((value, key, index) -> key ~= payload.unit and value ~= payload.cost))
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: Ok. but I have existing .java class and most of logic already in java class and I need to add this logic in the class only.  I am receiving A1289||B2234,A8976||B7765  combination value from a variable(example - test123 is variable name)  and for unit and cost also receiving values through variables (example - unit and cost variable names)in this class.  So I need a logic to compare test variable value with  unit and cost variable values.

Comment: In a simple way,  I am explaining as below :  
I will receive this value A1289||B2234,A8976||B7765 from test123 variable,
I have to compare values which I receive from variable unit and cost.  unit's value should match with A1289 and cost's value should match with B2234, if not match
then(2nd check) unit's value should match with A8976 and cost's value should match with B7765.

if it matchesthen need to print not matched   if matched then to print matched.

Comment: I'll post a Java answer when I can.

Comment: using a custom format like that should be changed for something more standard like JSON or XML if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in Java I created a simple class:

```
package org.cc.bu.combo;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UnitChecker {
    
    static private Map<String, String> parseCombo(String combo) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
        Map<String, String> c = pattern.splitAsStream(combo)
                .map(s -> {
                    String[] parts = s.split("\\|\\|");
                    return parts;
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p[0], p -> p[1]));
                
        return c;
    }
    
    static public boolean check(String combo, String unit, String cost) {
        Map<String, String> c = parseCombo(combo);
        String value = c.get(unit);
        return cost.equals(value);
    }
}
```

It can be called from a flow like this:

```
    <set-variable value="A1289||B2234,A8976||B7765" variableName="combos" />
    <java:invoke-static doc:name="Invoke static"  class="org.cc.bu.combo.UnitChecker" method="check(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)">
        <java:args ><![CDATA[#[{combo: vars.combos, unit: 'A1289', cost: 'B2234' }]]]></java:args>
    </java:invoke-static>
```

You need to add the [Java Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/java-module/1.2/) to the project (always use the last version) and also ensure you are compiling with [Java 8 source compatibility](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html). If you haven't previously, add the following properties to the pom:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```